# How To Calculate Mean In R (Data Structure)

Tags: r, mean

I have a data structure in R like so:

```
> tkr[[i, 4]]
[1] 81.3
> tkr[[i - 1, 4]]
[1] 82.59
> tkr[[i - 2, 4]]
[1] 80.69
> tkr[[i - 3, 4]]
[1] 79.76
> tkr[[i - 4, 4]]
[1] 81.19
> tkr[[i - 5, 4]]
[1] 77.71
> tkr[[i - 6, 4]]
[1] 77.9
> tkr[[i - 7, 4]]
[1] 75.06
> tkr[[i - 8, 4]]
[1] 72.76
> tkr[[i - 9, 4]]
[1] 75.5
```

I want to calculate the Mean of these 10 values (row index varies, column index stays constant at 4).

I have tried:   mean(tkr[i:i - 9, 4])  and I get 75.5 which is just the value of the last data point.

The mean is 78.446 - which is the value I am expecting.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
dput(head(tkr))

structure(c(71, 71, 73, 71.35, 69.7, 70.43, 72.5, 73.3, 73.45, 
71.35, 72, 71.27, 70.2, 70.56, 70.89, 70, 69.18, 67.06, 71.44, 
73.08, 71.1, 70.41, 70.28, 67.56, 116744, 150669, 146162, 153921, 
145007, 356811), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", src = "google", updated = structure(1415233768.37727, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1380585600, 
1380672000, 1380758400, 1380844800, 1381104000, 1381190400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(6L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("DATA.Open", "DATA.High", "DATA.Low", 
"DATA.Close", "DATA.Volume")))
```

Comment: Could you please add the result of `dput(head(tkr))` to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not put brackets:

```
mean(tkr[i:(i - 9), 4])
```

or:

```
mean(tkr[(i - 9):i, 4])
```